# Деление числа на разряды

Tags: c#, .net

Не знаю как сделать на c#. Помогите плз :\

Деление числа на разряды

Консоль:

> Введите пятизначное число: 10819

```
1 цифра равна 1 
2 цифра равна 0
3 цифра равна 8
4 цифра равна 1
5 цифра равна 9
```

http://cppstudio.com/post/2591/ Взято отсюда.

Comment: по ссылке на плюсах решение....не так уж и трудно переделать ег опод шарп

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Помоги если можешь, а то мне непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал:

```cs
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите 5-значное число :");
            int nums = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            string[] str = 
            {
                "Первая цифра равна:",
                "Вторая цифра равна:",
                "Третья цифра равна:",
                "Четвертая цифра равна:",
                "Пятая цифра равна:" };

            if (nums > 9999 && nums < 100000)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str[0] + (nums / 10000) % 10);
                Console.WriteLine(str[1] + (nums / 1000) % 10);
                Console.WriteLine(str[2] + (nums / 100) % 10);
                Console.WriteLine(str[3] + (nums / 10) % 10);
                Console.WriteLine(str[4] + (nums / 1) % 10);
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Вы ввели некорректное число");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Увижу у своих студентов копию поставлю пару)))